# How can you disable scrolling back up a webpage once you've reached the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scroll

I am making a webpage and I would like to disable the users to scroll back up the webpage once they have reached the bottom of the page. So while scrolling they can still scroll up and down, but once the end of the page is there, they can't scroll back to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As first you have to detect if the user is at the bottom of the page.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   //Prevent Scrolling
}
```

Preventing the user to scroll is a bit harder.
I found a solution for this: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)